# Minimalistic forum software like urbanbaby.com and FruitShow

Tags: php, forum

Building a forum. I need something completely minimalistic. A clean clutter-free non-clunky user-interface.

It doesn't have to be free, but it does need to be open-source.

Take a look at [urbanbaby.com](http://urbanbaby.com) , that's exactly what I want (edit: it's built in Ruby on Rails though... I seek a PHP equivalent.)

The closest I've found is FruitShow (for a demo, see [crazyontap.com](http://crazyontap.com) ). It is free and open-source.

What I particularly like about urbanbaby.com and crazyontap.com is the high-density of words on the page.

However, FruitShow hasn't been updated since 2007, so I'm wary of using it.

What alternatives do you know of? (I'd prefer something in PHP.)

Comment: That's not quite a forum - That site kinda reminds me of a discussion board, ala reddit, which might be a better thing to look for.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Agreed. I was using the terms as synonyms. Perhaps I shouldn't have. Can you recommend any discussion board software that would do an equivalent job of that site? (I've looked and haven't found anything close.)

Comment: Not from experience, since I'd have posted an answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Saito](http://saito.siezi.com/) looks good from their demo -

[image]

1. Very minimal UI, with a threaded option (Actually, even more minimal than your example), and one of the sites they mention as using their framework [looks identical](http://www.macfix.de/) to what you want
2. Its *relative* but as of the date I posted this answer, its updated
3. PHP/mysql based.

Installation *seems* sensible but I haven't tried an install of it myself yet. It does seem to rely on htaccess files for some things, but other than that I don't see anything that yells *run away!!!*

Comment: Hey Journeyman G., I can't for the life of me figure out how to install this thing. When I unzipped it, there was no .htaccess file in any folder. But the installation instructions (admin-install.md) say "Apache: `.htaccess` should take care of correct url, just open the url root." ... what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give identification first about **Urbanbaby**. I have checked the technology behind UrbanBaby.com using **Builtwith**. I got the results [here](http://builtwith.com/urbanbaby.com), you can look on the *frameworks* section (no Content/Forum Management System yet). The result show us that forum website didn't use [PHP](http://php.net) as the frameworks, but it was [**Ruby on Rails**](http://rubyonrails.org/) (RoR). Well, if you want use Ruby on Rails as the framework of your next forum software, I recommend to you using [**Discourse**](http://try.discourse.org/). You prefer using them in PHP than any other language.

Since you prefer PHP, I suggest to you the **alternative** of software forum which you have mentioned above, **FruitShow**. That is [**Vanilla forums**](http://vanillaforums.org/). I found interesting projects of the cross software forum between *FruitShow* and *Vanilla forums* (https://github.com/ruipacheco/fruitshow). Unfortunately, it was written in Python. Vanilla forums is written in PHP originally. If it's not enough, I suggest you using the popular PHP forum software, for example [**Simple Machine Forum**](http://www.simplemachines.org/) (SMF).

Comment: Thank you my friend. I was aware that UrbanBaby.com used RoR. I should have admitted that in my question. I don't know Rails though, so I was looking for a PHP equivalent. I was aware of the Python cross you mentioned (also called FruitShow), and I might go with that if I can't find anything else. I was aware of Vanilla, I appreciate your endorsement. I'm going to give it a serious look-through. The problem with the popular forum softwares (including SMF), is that they're not minimalistic (unless there's a theme out there that I'm unaware of).